# Excel 2003 DSUM not working

Tags: excel, excel-2003, worksheet-function

A client of mine has a major application written and running in excel 2003 ( I know, and they know, that it is a mistake, and they are waiting for it to be properly incorporated into their SAP application. They have been waiting for many years. ). Most of the time it works fine, however this week they had a problem, and the data was returning #value entries.

As I looking into this, I identified that a DSUM function was returning #value, which was then being spread across other places ( did I mention that there is no data verification in the VBA code? ) When I looked at the function, which is summing a column in a separate sheet, with a conditional, it identified a number of problems in the data, but even when I fixed them, and the Function analysis indicated no errors, it still returned #value.

I would post some of the code, but there is a 4700 row sheet involved, which is rather inpractical. Can anyone suggest what I might be able to do to progress this? Why is the DSUM returning #value problems, when there is no indication of any errors in the source sheet? I have searched through the column, and all of the values are valid numbers.

Sorry to be a little vague, but if anyone can give me suggestions as to how to progress, it would be appreciated. Excel and VBA are not my real specialities.

Comment: is there a possibility the data field or criteria headers have been changed or are no longer matching what is used in the formula?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell - I have an earlier backup where the formula works, so I can do comparisons.

Comment: I don't believe so. The sheet is only updated by the application, and was working previously. It feels like a problem with the data, but there is nothing indicated.

Comment: The client has rolled back and resolved this for now, but if anyone can answer how you progress this sort of problem, it would be very helpful for others. And maybe me next time.

Comment: What did they rollback from?  Also, you could might be able to migrate a lot of the calcs to VBA, which might fix things up.

Comment: I think it was a saved copy that they then had to add a load of data into. They need to migrate the whole lot to something sensible, but politics gets in the way. Maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get a #value was 3 fold:

1. If the criteria (the 3rd parameter) contained less that 2 cells.
2. If the data had a #VALUE in it that was propagated through.
3. Or if the first row of the database/table contained a value instead of text (even a number formatted as text fails in my example).

Do you still have the offending version of the spreadsheet?  Might be worth ensuring the first row of data for errors particularly cells that look like text but have values in them (i.e., cell formatting can be used to display text even if there is a value in the cell, or if the first row is also calculated).

Hope this helps, and do let us know how you get on.

Dave

Comment: 1. Criteria definately had 2 cells 2. The data I had checked through and there was no #value. 3. Possibly. I no longer have a copy of the sheet, so I cannot check. But thank you for looking into it. I will pass these on. And it will serve me as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting.  Do let me know if it doesn't work or if you need anything else.  Cheers Dave.